# How can I cast XNode to a custom type?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

My linq to xml query is

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
IEnumerable<XNode> lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("resources") select lv1.FirstNode;
```

which returns a list of

```
<entry>
  <key>keyName</key>
  <value>valueName</value>
</entry>
```

How can i convert the result of the query to a list of the following class?

```
  /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class entry
    {

        private string keyField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string key
        {
            get
            {
                return this.keyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.keyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you get are of type `XNode`, representing elements of XML. You cannot cast them, so you need to use `new` to create objects of your desired type:

```
var converted = lv1s.OfType<XElement>().Select(lv1 => new entry {
    key = lv1.Element("key").Value
,   value = lv1.Element("value").Value
});
```

Filtering `XNode`s down to `XElement` using `OfType<T>` lets you skip nodes of your XML tree that are not elements, e.g. comments.

Answer (score 3):

You could work with `XElement` instead of `XNode` and then you can do something like:

```
IEnumerable<entry> lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("resources") 
                             select  new entry {
                                  key = lv1.Element("key").Value, 
                                  value = lv1.Element("value").Value 
                             };
```

Comment: You can sling a `.ToList()` on the end if you need your collection to be a list